# SharePoint 2013 Composed Look - How to add .spcolor and .preview file to SP Server via VS package?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, solution-package, composed-looks

We are using VS2012 and SP2013.

Presently we are deploying a masterpage via VS module (without feature event receiver, so we are not activating it on deployment).

Then, creating a composed look with this masterpage via PowerShell. Now the problem is that, the composed look does not appear in the 'change the look and feel' unless you add a corresponding '.preview' file. Reference: [Check the pre-requisites section](http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/sharepoint-2013-composed-looks-getting-a-preview-picture-to-work/)

I need to know that:-

1. How do I place this .preview file via VS package into the 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL'?
2. We have also created a .spcolor file which needs to be uplaoded to 'themes/15 folder' via VS package.

Please guide. I guess we need to use the module project item. But what change to make in the elements.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a mapped folder in your project and place .preview file inside it.
   [image]
2. Add a module to the project and provide the url which references `/_catalogs/theme/15` in the XML file in order to place .spcolor file in it.